# How to change pathname of file in Java?

Tags: java, swing, file

I have a Save As... function in my text editor. I would like to do a Save As, save to a new file, but then my permanent file to save to should now always be this new file. So when I click my other button, Save, instead of saving to the previous location is will continue to save to the location which was selected with JFileChooser.

I have a File object called currentFile which should link to the file chosen via Save As. I am currently making sure of that by creating a file called fileName in my button action performed function, and then setting the currentFile to that file

```
    File fileName = new File(fileChoice.getSelectedFile() + ".txt");
    currentFile = fileName;
```

I was wondering if I could achieve the same thing without creating new file..? It appears to me that the new file creation follows the `File(String pathname)` constructor, yet there seems to be no method to set pathname of the file.

Comment: Generally the process of moving a file means you copy it to a new location, and delete the old file.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but it *sounds* as if you want to change the content of an existing `File` object to point to another. That's not possible, that class is immutable by design (i.e. you can't change what a `File` points to, you can just create a new `File` object with a different value). But since `File` is such a light-weight object (it's basically a wrapper around a `String`) creating a new `File` instance isn't expensive, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change File path, because as you can read in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20395623/2342240):

"Instances of the File class are immutable; that is, once created, the abstract pathname represented by a File object will never change"

so you need to create another instance of File.

Also [renameTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) method uses another instance of File as parameter to change the path

```
File fileToMove = new File("path/to/your/oldfile.txt");
boolean isMoved = fileToMove.renameTo(new File("path/to/your/newfile.txt"));
```

You can also read [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-how-to-rename-or-move-a-file), there are several ways to rename or move files.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking to change the path name but what you really want is to move the file. Files#move does this for you.

```java
Path path = Paths.get("my", "path", "to", "file.txt");

Path moveToPath = Paths.get("my", "path", "to", "moved", "file.txt");

Path moveResult = Files.move(path, moveToPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);

if (!moveToPath.equals(moveResult)) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to move file to requested location.");
}
```